# TinySound locks up application

Tags: java, audio, freeze

In my application, I am using [TinySound](https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound) for the sound system, but for some reason calling `TinySound.init()` will lock up my application and prevent it from doing anything else. Is this a bug with TinySound, or user error that can be fixed?

Comment: What type of application? How are you calling `TinySound`?

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded the latest (1.1.1) version of TinySound and run example from 
https://github.com/finnkuusisto/TinySound/blob/master/example/TinySoundExample.java

But edited code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //initialize TinySound
    TinySound.init();
    System.out.println("After init");
}
```

I got **After init** printed. So your issue is not related to `TinySound.init()` method directly. Most probably you start to play sound in the main thread. And the thread will be blocked until the whole file will be played.

Comment: I've created a new Thread and moved the TinySound example into it, yet even when I comment out the lines saying `song = TinySound.loadMusic();` and `titleSong.play(true);`, it still won't work until I comment out TinySound.init();.

Comment: Problem fixed - moved code to a place after the JFrames were created.